# Presto Performance Tuning Help: Multiple Left Joins Causing Long Runtime

Tags: sql, presto

I have a query that times out and I am hoping to understand why so I can fix it. The below code is intended to show how the joins are set up in my final CTE, the portion of the query that's making this take the longest.

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
    product_id AS integer
    , product_count1 AS integer
    , product_count2 AS integer
)

CREATE TABLE buckets (buckets) AS
    SELECT 
        CAST(buckets AS integer)
    FROM
        UNNEST(SEQUENCE(1,200,1)) t(buckets)
```

The orders table has millions of rows while the buckets table has 200. Here is the final CTE that's causing the problem.

```
SELECT
    t.buckets
    , COUNT(o1.product_count1) AS child_count
    , COUNT(o2.product_count2) AS parent_count
FROM
    UNNEST(SEQUENCE(1,200,1)) t(buckets)
LEFT JOIN
    orders o1
    ON t.buckets = o1.product_count1
LEFT JOIN
    orders o2
    ON t.buckets = o2.product_count1
GROUP BY
    t.buckets
```

The end result is to create two histograms derived from the final CTE above. The orders table has x number of products with 2 different types of counts for each product. I will count the number of products where product_count1 = 1, 2, 3 etc. and do the same against product_count2.

From what I understand, having a very small table declared first followed by two large tables being left joined is my problem. So my question is, how do I count against the buckets table so all rows in the buckets table are preserved and any value between 1 - 200 not found in the orders table will return 0 without declaring the small table first? For what it's worth, if I remove one of the left joins, it finishes in <7 minutes. I hope this makes sense, thank you in advance!